# fittext.js does not work and it drives me mad

Tags: jquery, css, fonts, font-size

I'am intergrating fittext.js in a website but is does do nothing. And I can't find the problem.

Maybe somebody else?

This is the code

```
CSS CODE

.nav-text {
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
display: block;
margin-top: 5px;
padding-top: 0px;
}

HTML CODE

<div class="nav small-4 large-2 columns padding_bottom_30"><a href="#"><img src="/img/wat-thumbnail.png" alt="Wat"><br/>
  <p class="nav-text">Wat</p></a></div>

JQUERY CODE

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--fit-text-->
<script src="/js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(".nav-text").fitText();
</script>
```

[Here's a link to a live working version.](http://voogelbv.businesscatalyst.com/)

Thanks so far!

Comment: A description of expected behavior versus actual behavior would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the the image and the p tag, and use the class of the p-tag in you jquery selector. Something like this:

```
<div>
<p><a href="#"><img src="/img/wat-thumbnail.png" alt="Wat"></a></p>
<p class="nav-text"><a href="#">Wat</a></p>
</div>
```